# Gaussian distribution with condition?

Tags: statistics, bayesian-statistics, robotics

## What does this expression mean?

### Normal distribution with condition

I am reading a research paper and found the following expression (Eq.28 in the paper below).

[image]

It means a Gaussian distribution, but the mean component seems conditional probability-like expression $\it{\bf{s}}_t | \it{\bf{m}}_{b, t, m}^{(j)}$.
I have never seen this expression before and cannot find any info about it.

The variables $\it{\bf{s}}_t$ and $\it{\bf{m}}_{b, t, m}^{(j)}$ are both vectors and $\bf{\Sigma}_{b}$ is a covariance matrix.

Does anybody have an idea of what this expression means?

### Original paper where the expression is.

The original paper can be found here: https://eprints.soton.ac.uk/437941/1/08340823.pdf

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The $m$ is the vector of means and $\Sigma$ the covariance of the multivariate normal distribution. The $s$ is in the place of the variable of the density function. So, $\mathcal{N}(x,m,\Sigma)=(2\pi)^{-k/2}|\Sigma|^{-1/2}\exp(-2^{-1}(x-m)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-m))$, where $k$ is the dimension of the vectors $x,m$ and $\Sigma$ is $k\times k$.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @plop, can you write that as an answer?  We discourage writing answers in the comments.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathcal{N}(x|m,\Sigma)=(2\pi)^{-k/2}|\Sigma|^{-1/2}\exp\left(-2^{-1}(x-m)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-m)\right)$$

where $x,m$ are vectors of dimension $k$, $\Sigma$ is a $k\times k$ matrix, $|\Sigma|$ is its determinant. The vector $m$ represents the mean of the multivariate normal, and $\Sigma$ the covariance matrix, which must be positive definite.